# Why this converter needs casting?

Tags: java, generics, enums, vavr

I need to implement an enum to enum converter in java: `Enum_2` > `Enum_1` and I'd like to do it in generic way.

So I defined an interface:

```
interface LabelAware<T extends Enum> {
    String getLabel();

    T getObject();
}
```

and `Enum_1`:

```
enum Enum_1 {
    A, B;

    String getValue() {
        return "whatever";
    }
}
```

and `Enum_2` which implements `LabelAware` and needs to be converted to `Enum_1`:

```
enum Enum_2 implements LabelAware<Enum_1> {
    C("c", Enum_1.A), D("d", Enum_1.B);

    private final String label;
    private final Enum_1 object;

    Enum_2(String label, Enum_1 object) {
        this.label = label;
        this.object = object;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public Enum_1 getObject() {
        return object;
    }
}
```

Finally, here's a generic converter (`List.ofAll()` comes from [javaslang](http://www.javaslang.io/)):

```
class Converter<S extends LabelAware, D extends Enum> {

    private S[] values;

    Converter(S[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    D map(String label) {
        return (D) List.of(values)
                .find(v -> v.getLabel().equals(label))
                .map(LabelAware::getObject)
                .getOrElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(""));
    }
}
```

And a main method:

```
public class Main {        
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(new Converter<Enum_2, Enum_1>(Enum_2.values()).map("c").getValue());
   }
}
```

It all compiles and runs well, however I've no idea why I need to cast the result of `Converter.map` method to `D`, since I've declared `D` to extend `Enum`. Can it be done in a generic way without any warnings?

Comment: Isn't `List.of(values)` of type `S`?

Comment: I'm on my phone so it's hard to read,  but note that Enum is a generic class, so your generics include a raw type as written. Typically you'll want `<T extends Enum <T>>`. Not sure if that's your issue.

Comment: @yshavit, it changes nothing - unchecked warning is still present.

Comment: @EliSadoff, will be. Mind that `S` itself is parametrized to return `Enum<T>` so it should be caught.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule, all warnings related to generics should be handled to have a safer code and avoid a warning chain (the visible warning is caused by a very far warning of the dependency chain).

But in your case, you have not a warning chain problem since externally, `LabelAware` is safe. 
 `LabelAware` has only a internal warning (in its implementation) as `Enum` in `extends Enum` is raw-declared.

Here, a single missing generic declaration explains why the cast in `Converter.map()` method  is not safe : `Converter` class declaration doesn't specify the generic for `LabelAware`.

You declare `Converter` class as :

```
class Converter<S extends LabelAware, D extends Enum> {
```

with its `value` field of type `S`:

```
 private S[] values;
```

and its `map()` method as :

```
 D map(String label) {
        return (D) List.of(values)
                .find(v -> v.getLabel().equals(label))
                .map(LabelAware::getObject)
                .getOrElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(""));
    }
```

In `map()`, here `.find(v -> v.getLabel().equals(label))`, your retrieve so a `S` instance and you declared that `S extends LabelAware`.
Therefore finally, your retrieve an instance of `LabelAware` or extending it.

And `LabelAware` is typed with `Enum` generic :

```
interface LabelAware<T extends Enum> {
    String getLabel();    
    T getObject();
}
```

So, in `map()` method when `.map(LabelAware::getObject)` is called, you retrieve a `Enum` type .

And an `Enum` type is not necessarily a `D` type, while the reverse is true.

Therefore, if you want to avoid the cast (and the related warning) in `map()`, you should specify that the generic type returned by `getObject()` is an instance of `D` by typing `LabelAware` with `D` generic :

```
class Converter<S extends LabelAware<D>, D extends Enum> {
```

Answer (score 5):

You have been using raw types at several places (not only the one that yshavit pointed out in the comment). Particularly, the

```
class Converter<S extends LabelAware, D extends Enum>
```

has to be

```
class Converter<S extends LabelAware<D>, D extends Enum<D>>
```

The following should compile without warnings:

```
import javaslang.collection.List;

interface LabelAware<T extends Enum<?>>
{
    String getLabel();

    T getObject();
}

enum Enum_1
{
    A, B;

    String getValue()
    {
        return "whatever";
    }
}

enum Enum_2 implements LabelAware<Enum_1>
{
        C("c", Enum_1.A), D("d", Enum_1.B);

    private final String label;
    private final Enum_1 object;

    Enum_2(String label, Enum_1 object)
    {
        this.label = label;
        this.object = object;
    }

    public String getLabel()
    {
        return label;
    }

    public Enum_1 getObject()
    {
        return object;
    }
}

class Converter<S extends LabelAware<D>, D extends Enum<D>>
{

    private S[] values;

    Converter(S[] values)
    {
        this.values = values;
    }

    D map(String label)
    {
        return List.of(values)
            .find(v -> v.getLabel().equals(label))
            .map(LabelAware::getObject)
            .getOrElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(""));
    }
}
```

(EDIT: This only tells you how to fix the problem, pragmatically. See the [answer by davidxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40440186/3182664) for details about what went wrong there, and don't forget to leave a +1 there :-))